# Deployment error, Access to tomcat not authorized error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, netbeans

My `tomcat-users.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I try to build the project, I get error:

```
Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

In servers window of netbeans I have provided same username and password. I have installed Tomcat 7.0 installed. I don't know what this problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```